# Horizontalscrollview with huge number of views optimization?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

**i have an app that looks like pulse https://lh5.ggpht.com/JPrFfuPBYwxBKQYcqSxdmdBWsJPRfZAiYmnKboFBI3V8Zqq7GqTUG9R_sCui3KIL1g ,
that it has about 8-10 news sections in each section there is about 20-30 stories, my current design is that every section is a horizontalscrollview that contains 20-30 stories , 
this is my suedo main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout>
 <HorizontalScrollView>
  <LinearLayout orientation:horizontal>
   <RelativeLayout id:singlenewsstory>
    <Imageview/>
      <TextView/>
   <RelativeLayout/>
   <RelativeLayout id:singlenewsstory>
    <Imageview/>
      <TextView/>
   <RelativeLayout/>
    etc...
  <LinearLAyout/>
 <horizontalScrollView>
 <HorizontalScrollView>
  <LinearLayout orientation:horizontal>
   <RelativeLayout id:singlenewsstory>
    <Imageview/>
      <TextView/>
  <RelativeLayout/>
  <RelativeLayout id:singlenewsstory>
    <Imageview/>
      <TextView/>
  <RelativeLayout/>
  etc...
 <LinearLAyout/>
<horizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView>
 <LinearLayout orientation:horizontal>
  <RelativeLayout id:singlenewsstory>
    <Imageview/>
      <TextView/>
  <RelativeLayout/>
  <RelativeLayout id:singlenewsstory>
    <Imageview/>
      <TextView/>
 <RelativeLayout/>
    etc...
 <LinearLAyout/>
  <horizontalScrollView>
    etc...
```

of course i fill my layout dynamically but my main concern that with this design , there would be about 200 views in the activity and about 150 images which may slow the app.
i hae several questions:

1-each scroll view will have at most 3 news stories visible in screen bounds, does horizontalscrollview optimize this by not drawing out of bound views.?

2-is Horizontalscrollview appropriate for what iam doing or there is something else i can use ?

3-i am putting al these horizontal scrollviews into one vertical scrollview but one i scroll one horizontally the vertical scrollview also scrolls by a small amount.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace your scrollviews with listviews?  Listviews only draw whats on screen, and it sounds like you are scrolling through a repeating set of views.

Comment: yes i am scrolling through a repeated set of views , but isn't list view for vertical scrolling only?

Comment: I had assumed there was a horizontal list, but it appears I was wrong.  I found this, but I don't know how good it is.

https://github.com/vieux/Android-Horizontal-ListView

Comment: But you agree that this design would be too many views in a single screen?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I can only imagine the amount of time it would take to inflate all those views, load/set all the images, and the memory it would take, all of which could probably do with some optimization.